# Was fish permitted for consumption before the Mabul?

Tags: eating, fish, mabul

Were Noachides allowed to consume fish, which is not considered Fleishigs, before the Mabul?

After the Mabul meat was permitted, but what about fish?

Comment: Noahides = Bnei Noach = Shem, Yafet and Cham?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10914/759

Comment: What about chicken and grasshoppers?